# Objective-C: Как использовать scrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview

У меня есть `scrollView` с 6 экранами. Использую его с paging mode. Когда я нажимаю на `nextButton` перехожу к следующему экрану. Нажимаю на `backButton` перехожу на предыдущий экран. Все отлично работает, если я начинаю прокрутку с первого экрана. Но если я нажму на `nextButton` и начну прокручивать с 5 экрана, я перехожу на 2-й экран. Как нормально скролить с каждого экрана?

**nextButton**

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    if(self.currentPage == 6) return;
    self.currentPage++;
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scroller.frame.size.width;
    [_scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth*self.currentPage, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

**backButton**

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    if(self.currentPage == 0) return;
    self.currentPage--;
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scroller.frame.size.width;
    [_scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth*self.currentPage, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: когда вы прокручиваете `self.currentPage` не меняется, таким образом, при нажатии next он прыгает на currentPage. вам надо изменять currentPage в методах делегата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте этот метод делегата `UIScrollView`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if ([scrollView isEqual:_scroller]) {
    CGFloat pageWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
    CGFloat pageFraction = self.scrollImage.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSLog(@"%d", (NSInteger)pageFraction);
}
}
```

В `NSLog` Выводится числовой параметр выбранного вами скрола, при нажатии на кнопку вам надо умножать вашу ширину на этот чиловой параметр + 1 (это если происходит перелистывание право, если надо скролить влево меняете параметр на -1)